# Difference between //*/ and /*// in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I cannot figure out the difference between:

```
/RootNode//*/@* (1)
```

and

```
/RootNode/*//@* (2)
```

May be `(1)` says "start from the `RootNode` go deep as you can until you find all leaves with any attribute to print and then print it" and the
`(2)` says "Start at `RootNode`, take all elements (only children of `RootNode`) and then go as deep as you can until you find a leaf with an attribute to print". Am I wrong?  What is the difference between `(1)` and  `(2)` ?

Comment: What makes you think there's a difference? Do you have something that works with one but not the other, for example?

Comment: In my opinion nothing. They should display the same result. But I wrote the solution `(1)`, my prof put a big red "X" on it and wrote the `(2)`. I do not understand why. If they are the same then if one is correct, the other is too.

Comment: Actually it can also be written `/RootNode//@*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both equivalent.  They both say,

> Select all of the attributes on elements beneath the top `RootNode` element.

Whether the `*` appears before or after the descendant-or-self step doesn't matter.

Comment: thank you for editing but i think `/RootNode/*//data/@*` should stay `/RootNode/*//data(@*)` because `data` is not a part of path but a function that print values of atributes. Right?

Comment: I'm asked to display all attributes in a document and if I type `/RootNode/*//data(@*)` it works, if I try `/RootNode/*//@*` it doesn't. Error: `Error on line 1 of *module with no systemId*:
  XPTY0004: Cannot create an attribute node (name) whose parent is a document node
Cannot create an attribute node (name) whose parent is a document node`

Comment: `//@*` will select all attribute values in a document; you don't need `data()`, but I will remove `data` as an element if that's not what was your intention.

Comment: Regarding your error message:  Perhaps ask another question and create a [mcve].   It's hard to tell from here, but if you're using XSLT and trying to output selected attributes without an associated element, you could see that error.  Maybe you want `<xsl:value-of select="//@*/>" in order to convert to string values so that you don't need an associated element for the attributes.

Comment: The error message "Cannot create an attribute node" doesn't mean the expression is wrong, it just means you are using it in a context where the result has the wrong type - just as if you wrote "2+2" in a context where a node is expected.